# Application Freezing after some idle time

Tags: c#, desktop-application

I am developing a software using C# 2.0 which uses about 200MB of memory and occasionally high CPU. The problem is, when i am leaving my machine idle for about 20-30 mins with the application running, after i come back and try to use the application, it freezes for about 2 mins, then becomes interactive.

Why does this happen? Is there any way to avoid this?

Thank you all.

Regards,

-Rakib

Comment: Your application needs love. What were you doing? Need loads of details - how much RAM ur computer has, what kind of processor.. and finally, what is the piece of code that you suspect could be the problem. :)

Comment: Sorry, for not giving enough info. My system's RAM is 4GB, processor is Core 2 Duo 2.4GHz. And I saw that, before i try to access my application, if i see the memory usage from Task Manager, I see only 1 or 2MB is used. But right after I try to access my application, memory usage rises to about 100MB.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "accessing" your app? Do you mean when you try to use your machine after inactivity or something else?

Comment: "Accessing" means for example, if the application is minimized, after 20-30mins of idle time, i am trying to restore it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a wild guess, but perhaps your app's memory pages are getting swapped out when its idle, and back in when you resume.

Either that or your UI thread is blocking on something.  We'd need more details to really diagnose.

Comment: I think, you are right. It seems like memory pages are getting swapped. But how do I prevent this from happening?

Comment: If memory pages are the problem, then this is OS problem. Maybe you can increase the page file size?

Comment: @Nayan the page file is what its getting swapped *to*, which is what you want to avoid.  I wouldn't think increasing its size would help (if this is truly the cause).

@Rakib: could you give us info about how much free memory you have?

Comment: If its the OS problem, why doesn't it happen with other applications? Wouldn't increasing the page file size will increase the tendency to move my used memory to page file?

Comment: @Collin: In such situation, I typically have about 1GB free memory.

Comment: The amount of memory Rakib mentioned is about 200 MB, which is not small amount. You also understand that OS controls the loading and unloading of application independently. If you increase, page size, the OS has no tendency to put more data in pagefile. It's just all defined by the settings (if any, eg. Firefox has some setting like when you minimize, it reduces the RAM usage) and requirement of free RAM. In 20-30 idle mins, there could be some applications or even OS which need more free RAM to work upon something. Also, as Hans said, defragging also helps to speed up reading pagefile.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old thread, but I stumbled on this upon searching answer for similar problem.

For me using timer triggered renderTargetBitmap during display turn off on idle (Vista, control panel) used pretty soon all of the memory and computer freezed.

You can find more details here:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/4a4ab601-f832-49ac-aca5-1f537fec1d04

(MSDN Forums - .Net development Forums - WPF - Huge memory consumption starts after 20 minutes

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to answer such a question with the minimal information giving.

Some guesses:

- Garbage Collection kicks in (nog very likely?)
- Some system resources are accessed
- UI Thread is blocking

Comment: This is not an answer. It could have been a comment though.

Comment: Add to that .. paging and disk issues?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use some [**.NET Profiler**](http://dotnet-profiler.com/) to figure out what part of code or thread is causing high CPU or memory usage